# How would this table be normalized?

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am trying to develop an android application which able to register a device to a specific email. Each email is unique and they can consist of many devices. Also, each of the devices can only have a single email.

I wish to normalize this table.

[image: Table to be normalized]

So my solution to the problem was:

[image]

Is this correct??

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: this is ok. However, you can also make join table to link devices to e-mails, so can expand application to many:many in future. Like tabla:device-email (device:pk, usertable:pk).

Comment: "Normalize" has two common meanings--converting a non-relational table to a relational table, & decomposing a relational table to higher normal forms. You did both. But you didn't give a first relational table, & decomposing (& PKs) requires knowing all functional dependencies, but you didn't give them. You gave some info about the application. But we have to do a lot of *guessing* about your application and table meanings. Our getting your design doesn't mean you got to it correctly. So justify your answer. Please read [ask].  PS Decomposing does not introduce, drop or change column names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should do.

The relation between user and logged-in devices is 1-n. So the Device table should contain a FK to refer to User table.